# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type'). Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So, i am trying to setup redux in my project. And there is very strange problem showing up in reducer: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type').
Here is reducer.ts:

```
import { MarkerActionEnum, MarkerActions, MarkerState } from './types';

const initialState: MarkerState = {
  data: undefined,
};

export function MarkerReducer(
  action: MarkerActions,
  state = initialState,
): MarkerState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MarkerActionEnum.ADD_MARKER:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    case MarkerActionEnum.DELETE_MARKER: {
      return { data: undefined };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default MarkerReducer;
```

and types.ts for reducer:

```
import { Action } from 'redux';
import { MarkerType } from '../../pages/mapPage/components/CustomMap';

export interface MarkerState {
  data: MarkerType | undefined;
}

export enum MarkerActionEnum {
  ADD_MARKER = 'marker/ADD_MARKER',
  DELETE_MARKER = 'marker/DELETE_MARKER',
}

export interface AddMarkerInterface
  extends Action<MarkerActionEnum.ADD_MARKER> {
  type: MarkerActionEnum.ADD_MARKER;
  payload: { longitude: number; latitude: number };
}

export interface DeleteMarkerInterface
  extends Action<MarkerActionEnum.DELETE_MARKER> {
  type: MarkerActionEnum.DELETE_MARKER;
}

export type MarkerActions = AddMarkerInterface | DeleteMarkerInterface;
```

Log says that the problem occurs in line 11 of reducer, right in `switch (action.type)`
Does anyone know or stumbled in something like this?

Comment: As a side note: it looks like you're may be using some legacy-style patterns for Redux+React-Redux. "Modern Redux" with Redux Toolkit and the React-Redux hooks API should help simplify your code and be easier to work with, _especially_ if you're using TS.  (Like, that entire separate "reducer types" file would go away completely!)  See our Redux docs tutorials for details: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/overview , as well as https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#avoid-action-type-unions .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem is the ordering of the parameters. "State" should be the first and "action" the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it means you have used as argument to `dispatch` something that is not an action, i.e. has no `type` property. For example if you have an action builder and forgot the parentheses, like in `dispatch(myActionBuilder)` instead of `dispatch(myActionBuilder())`.

Comment: but it still should return default state isn't it?

Comment: No, because it throws an error at `switch (action.type)`, so it never reaches the return statement. Just `console.log(action)` before that point and you will understand where the problem comes from.